# Any way to tweak Windows' kernels or drives to handle I/O and reduce or eliminate hangs with failing drives?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, kernel, io, hard-drive-failure

I frequently work with failing hard drives for data recovery and various tasks. These tasks are usually short lived in nature, but important. The way Windows seems to handle any failing drive that's attached either via SATA or USB, etc. seems to create hanging scenarios where any app that attempts to access a drive or drives (even apps that probably shouldn't be accessing the drive in question) causes the app(s) to just behave terribly.

The Linux kernel seems to generally handle failing drives much better and even NTFS options for Linux (and macOS) tend to handle these scenarios much better. The problem I find is that some of the software that I need for key extraction and other tools simply don't run on them and have a hard time operating via WINE.

Is there any way to tune or tweak the Windows kernel or drive drivers to not force blocking events and therefore allow the OS and programs to function more fluidly without long crippling hangs when dealing with failing hardware?